Need to query locked out user against a list of computer names on network to find where session is hung
***Update
I have revised the powershell code to code in another direction to get the reults I am looking for. This code is working and running through the list of computers. But I am getting reports on results for EVERY computer. All I wnat is the computers that match the criteria in the loop. How do I stop receiving notifications of computers without a user on it?


$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$total = $computers.Count
$counter = 0
$stringToMatch = "No User exists for *"
$lockedOutUser = 'rdiring'

foreach ( $computer in $computers )
{
    $quserResult = query user /server:$computer
    $counter++
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    $percentComplete = ($counter / $total) * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing computers" -Status "Computer $counter of $total" -PercentComplete $percentComplete
    If ( $quserResult.Count -gt 0 )
{
    If ( $quserResult -match $stringToMatch) {
        break
        } else {
            $quserRegex = $quserResult | ForEach-Object -Process { $_ -replace '\s{2,}',',' }
            $quserObject = $quserRegex | ConvertFrom-Csv
            $userSession = $quserObject | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.USERNAME -eq $lockedOutUser }
            If ( $userSession )
            {
                print($computer + $userSession)
            } else {
                Continue
            }
    } else {
        Continue
    }
    }

}



I want to develop a function that will perform the following:

Take the input of a userID of a locked out user
Import a list of known computer names
For each computer name in the list, run the 'query user /server:*' powershell script
Return results for the script line and parse out the different sections into objects to make them searchable
If the userID given in initial input is found within one of the lines, return that computer name with the line, at the end of the code

My frustration is occurring at phase 4. Parsing the line has become difficult. When the code below runs, it returns zero errors in PS, but the output file is blank.
$names = Get-Content $InputFile
$names = @()
foreach ($name in $names){
    try { 
        $Lines = @(query user /server:$name) -split "\n"
            foreach($Line in $Lines) {
                if ($Line -match "USERNAME\s+SESSIONNAME\s+ID\s+STATE\s+IDLE TIME\s+LOGON TIME") {
                    $Parsed_Server = $Line -split '\s+'
                    $names += [PSCustomObject]@{
                        SERVER = $Name
                        USERNAME = $Parsed_Server[1]
                        SESSIONNAME = $Parsed_Server[2]
                        ID = $Parsed_Server[3]
                        STATE = $Parsed_Server[4]
                        IDLE_TIME = $Parsed_Server[5]
                        LOGON_TIME = $Parsed_Server[6]
                    }
                } else {
                    -errorAction silentlyContinue
                }
        }
    } catch {
        Continue
    }
} $names | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoType

I messed around with the code a few times. I even ran a simplified version of the code and got the results to parse in PS for one declared computer name. I was silly though and only got it to do that once, and did not save the progress, and can't remember what I changed.
Was trying to get find it again, to put in this post. Alas, I am running out of time and figured that there was (hopefully) enough info here to get started on the community providing an answer.

The second line in your code $names = @() sets variable $names  to become an empty array. Next you try to iterate that same empty array (which of course will not enter the loop at all because $names is empty). Finally, you save this still empty array do disk..

As an aside: Extending arrays in a loop with += is inefficient, because a new array must be created behind the scenes in every iteration, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a foreach loop as an expression and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: [array] $outputs = foreach (...) { ... } - see this answer. In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create multiple  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see here.

The way I solved this at a previous job was remotely connected to each domain controller and searched for EventID 4740 which would contain either the name or the IP Address of the computer that was causing the lockout. You could also use 4625 on each member server or computer but auditing would have had to have been enabled previously.
In most of my experiences this was a user who does not log off their remote desktop sessions and they are RDP to a server and then they change passwords. That old RDP session goes to refresh periodically sending the old credz and causing the lockout.
Unfortunetly that is not one of my scripts that I backed up when I left that job. But to me this is a faster method of finding where the lockout occured in the first place.
I also recently found a more PowerShell...ish way to find logged on users
on my github page shameless plug
The only problem with EventID 4740 is your AD would have to have the proper auditing setup and Active Directory "out of the box" does not have that you would have had to priorly set it up like this article describes.
The sad thing is way back in the day Novell NDS had this feature built right in and you could right click a user from the directory and force all their logons to log off. NDS was ahead of its time in some ways, but ultimetly Microsoft's directory won out.
